# Oracle OUD enabling replication on 2 servers error detected: reading registration information error detected after dsreplication enable command

Tags: replication

After trying to enable replication on two OUD (Oracle Unified Directory) servers with command `dsreplication enable` I detected this error below:

`Error reading registration information.  Details: java.lang.NullPointerException See /tmp/oud-replication-8233460858614018565.log for a detailed log of this operation.`

Hi all,

My goal is to enable the replication on 2 Oracle Unified directory servers.

According to the Oracle official documentation the command must be used to reach this goal is this one below:

`/opt/instances/<instance_name>/bin/dsreplication enable --host1 <hostname1_FQDN> --port1 <port_admin> --bindDN1 "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPasswordFile1 <password_path_stored_file> --replicationPort1 8989  --host2  <hostname2_FQDN> --port2 <port_admin> --bindDN2 "cn=Directory Manager"  --bindPasswordFile2 <password_path_stored_file> --replicationPort2 8989 --adminUID admin --adminPasswordFile <admin_path_pwd_file> --baseDN "dc=example,dc=com" -X -n`

Unfortunatelly, after the execution of the command I found this error:

`Error reading registration information.  Details: java.lang.NullPointerException See /<path>/oud-replication-8233460858614018565.log for a detailed log of this operation.`

In the log file there is nothing can be considered usuful and the sole error I found is this below:

`INFO: Jul 31, 2023 2:18:12 PM org.opends.server.tools.common.GenericExecutor printProgress INFO: Done. Jul 31, 2023 2:18:12 PM org.opends.server.tools.common.GenericExecutor println WARNING: Error reading registration information.  Details: java.lang.NullPointerException See /tmp/oud-replication-8233460858614018565.log for a detailed log of this operation. Jul 31, 2023 2:18:12 PM org.opends.server.tools.replication.common.AbstractSubcommandExecutor execute SEVERE: org.opends.server.tools.replication.common.ReplicationToolException: Error reading registration information.  Details: java.lang.NullPointerException org.opends.server.tools.replication.common.ReplicationToolException: Error reading registration information.  Details: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.EnableExecutor.hasAdminInRegistrationProvider(EnableExecutor.java:2036) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.EnableExecutor.updateWithGlobalAdministrator(EnableExecutor.java:4088) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.EnableExecutor.updateUserDataNotInteracting(EnableExecutor.java:4072) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.EnableExecutor.internalExecute(EnableExecutor.java:236) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.EnableExecutor.internalExecute(EnableExecutor.java:179) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.common.AbstractSubcommandExecutor.execute(AbstractSubcommandExecutor.java:198) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.DSReplication.executeSubcommand(DSReplication.java:387) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.DSReplication.execute(DSReplication.java:348) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.DSReplication.execute(DSReplication.java:202) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.DSReplication.mainCLI(DSReplication.java:154) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.DSReplication.main(DSReplication.java:88) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at oracle.idm.oud.topologyapi.impl.registration.RegistrationEntryProviderImpl.getGlobalAdministrator(RegistrationEntryProviderImpl.java:127) at oracle.idm.oud.topologyapi.impl.registration.extension.GroupRegistrationEntryProviderImpl.getGlobalAdministrator(GroupRegistrationEntryProviderImpl.java:368) at oracle.idm.oud.topologyapi.impl.registration.ModifiableAdminRegistrationProviderImpl.getAdministrators(ModifiableAdminRegistrationProviderImpl.java:337) at oracle.idm.oud.topologyapi.impl.registration.extension.GroupAdministrationRegistration.getAdministrators(GroupAdministrationRegistration.java:309) at org.opends.server.tools.common.CustomRegistrationProvider.getAdministrators(CustomRegistrationProvider.java:91) at org.opends.server.tools.replication.dsreplication.EnableExecutor.hasAdminInRegistrationProvider(EnableExecutor.java:2028) ... 10 more`

I can also affirm that the port 8989 are opened and not occupied becuase the output of the command

`netstat -an | grep 8989 | grep -i listen`

is blank.

My target is to enable the replication of my OUD instance between 2 server bbut the error does not allow me to reach this target; could you pleae help me ?